# Setting up multiple Ubuntu computers to share files and users

Tags: file-sharing, ldap, user-management, multiple-workstations

I'm very new to the *nix world and only vaguely have heard of things like YP/NIS, LDAP, Kerberos, etc. If I have several machines that I want to toss Ubuntu on to and share users and files/mounts across them, what programs and services provide the necessary elements to do so?

I have a computer with more storage that can serve as a server, but what do I need to install and configure on it and all my workstations to-be? The network is shared with other, unknown groups, so security is important.

I don't really expect a detailed answer here; my problem is more I don't know where to start. LDAP *sounds* interesting, but it seems to do so many things I don't know if it's actually what to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use LDAP and NFS.

- LDAP can do a lot of things - and it is best suited to what you are doing for authentication. Managing LDAP is not a big chore, especially with utilities like `phpLDAPadmin`. There are plenty of scripts in the `ldapscripts` package to simplify command-line tasks. The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html) has a nice, detailed entry on installing and configuring LDAP and enabling STARTTLS. Once the server is set up, configuring the client is very easy - just install `libpam-ldapd`, `libnss-ldapd` and `nslcd` and choosing the right options when asked, and run the `pam-auth-update` command to enable LDAP. LDAP can also specify a lot of details about the user - the home directory, the shell, the mail server, etc.
- NFS can be used to share home folders, but I am not sure of securing it. You can allow and deny access to specific hosts, but I don't know how secure an IP-based restriction is - what's to prevent someone from using the IP of a system that's down and gaining access?

I have never set up Kerberos, so I won't comment about it, but it seems you can integrate Kerberos with LDAP and NFS, considerably increasing the security of NFS. But for now, start small with LDAP and NFS.